# Сколько уровней изоляций транзакций действует в database Oracle?

Tags: база-данных, oracle

И какое значение имеет DEFAULT?

Comment: Какие уровни будут установлены клиентами в данный момент времени, столько и будет действовать. Остальные, очевидно, будут бездействовать:)

Answer (score 1):

Из ранее приведенного документа.

> Oracle Database provides the transaction isolation levels:  Read Committed Isolation Level,  Serializable Isolation Level, Read-Only Isolation Level

Три, но Read-Only Isolation Level во-первых не ANSI, во вторых просто разновидность Serializable. Потому часто говорят, что два.

Read uncommitted, Repeatable read в Оракле нет.

По умолчанию Read Committed.

Answer (score -2):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e25789/consist.htm

т.е. 4 и read commited по умолчанию.

Зачем задавать вопросы, ответы на которые явно есть в документации?